Add only one figure label for multiple subfigures
I have a figure that contains 4 subfigures and want to add only one figure label on the left top corner, say (A). How can I add that line in my code below?
data("iris")

iris1 <- iris2 <- iris3 <- iris

fig <- list()

fig[[1]] <- ggplot(data=iris,mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Petal.Width,color=Species))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="lm") +
  labs(title = paste0("the title is ", expression(m[0])))

fig[[2]] <- ggplot(data=iris1,mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Petal.Width,color=Species))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="lm") +
  labs(title = paste0("the title is ", expression(m[1])))

fig[[3]] <- ggplot(data=iris2,mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Petal.Width,color=Species))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="lm") +
  labs(title = paste0("the title is ", expression(m[2])))

fig[[4]] <- ggplot(data=iris3,mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Petal.Width,color=Species))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="lm") +
  labs(title = paste0("the title is ", expression(m[3])))

 fig_all <- ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = fig, ncol = 2, nrow = 2, common.legend = TRUE, legend = "top")

 fig_all

The generated figure is as follows, but there is no figure label. I don't want to have label for each subfigures, but instead just one label to indicate for all, on the top left corner.


You can use ggpubr::annotate_figure
library("ggplot2")
library("ggpubr")
data("iris")

fig <- list()

fig[[1]] <- ggplot(data=iris,mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Petal.Width,color=Species))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="lm")

fig[[2]] <- ggplot(data=iris,mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Petal.Width,color=Species))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="lm")

fig[[3]] <- ggplot(data=iris,mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Petal.Width,color=Species))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="lm")

fig[[4]] <- ggplot(data=iris,mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Petal.Width,color=Species))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="lm")

fig_all <- ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = fig, ncol = 2, nrow = 2, common.legend = TRUE, legend = "top")

ggpubr::annotate_figure(fig_all, 
                        fig.lab = 'Main Title',
                        fig.lab.pos = 'top.left',
                        fig.lab.size = 16, 
                        fig.lab.face = 'bold')


Instead of ggpubr, try the patchwork package
So for your code, instead of fig[[x]], assign each figure to a object itself, e.g. fig1, fig2, fig3, fig4
and then collect them
fig1 + fig2 + fig3 + fig4 + plot_layout(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, guides = "collect")
To get the overall titles, you need to add plot_annotation()
Overall code would be:
data("iris")

iris1 <- iris2 <- iris3 <- iris

fig <- list()

fig1 <- ggplot(data=iris,mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Petal.Width,color=Species))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(method="lm") +
    labs(title = paste0("the title is ", expression(m[0])))

fig2 <- ggplot(data=iris1,mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Petal.Width,color=Species))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(method="lm") +
    labs(title = paste0("the title is ", expression(m[1])))

fig3 <- ggplot(data=iris2,mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Petal.Width,color=Species))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(method="lm") +
    labs(title = paste0("the title is ", expression(m[2])))

fig4 <- ggplot(data=iris3,mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Petal.Width,color=Species))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(method="lm") +
    labs(title = paste0("the title is ", expression(m[3])))
fig1 + fig2 + fig3 + fig4 + plot_layout(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, guides = "collect") + plot_annotation(
    title = 'Here is a title',
    subtitle = 'here is a subtitle',
    caption = 'here is a caption'
)


Here's the link for the package: https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/
